# Create your own Winston logger files

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

Here is a basic winston logger I set up:

```
var winston = require('winston')

var systemLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'system-file',
      // log which stores all the errors
      filename: './test.log',
      json: true,
      timestamp: true
    })
  ]
})

systemLogger.log('info', 'hello')
systemLogger.log('error', '-----hello2')
```

This create a log file like this:

```
{"level":"info","message":"hello","timestamp":"2016-08-18T11:48:22.081Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"-----hello2","timestamp":"2016-08-18T11:48:22.083Z"}
```

But I would like to make it look like this in the file:

```
INFO: 2016-08-18T11:48:22.081Z hello 
ERROR: 2016-08-18T11:48:22.083Z *** -----hello2 ***
```

Is that possible?

I read this - https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format but I cant actually find how to do this - if possible at all.

I have tried adding a formatter:

```
  formatter: function(options) {
    // Return string will be passed to logger.
    if (options.level === 'error') {
      return options.timestamp() +' ******** '+ options.level.toUpperCase() +' ******** '+ (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') 
    }
    else if (options.level === 'info') {
      return options.timestamp() +' '+ options.level.toUpperCase() +' '+ (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') 
    }
  }
```

However this only seems to work for Console prints, not for File. As teh file saves the same way as without the formatter.

Comment: My answer has examples for both file and console.

Answer (score 0):

In your code for logger setup you have to put formatter and whatever you string you return from formatter it will display in your log file.

```
formatter: function(options) {
        // Return string will be passed to logger.
        return options.timestamp() +' '+ options.level.toUpperCase() +' '+ (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') +
          (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? '\n\t'+ JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '' );
      }
```

So, The above formatter will print timestamp first followed by log level then the actual message you log.

Hope this helps....

Comment: I tried this but the file does not get saved correctly. Please check updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a formatter function:

```
$ cat logger.js 
var winston = require('winston');

module.exports = (function(){

    function formatter (args){
            var timestamp = new Date().toISOString(),
                level =  args.level.toUpperCase(),
                message = args.message;

        return level+": "+timestamp+" "+message ;
    }

    return new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.Console)({
                formatter: formatter,
            }),

            new (winston.transports.File)({
                formatter: formatter,
                filename : "./logs/custom-logger.log",
                maxsize : 1024 * 1024 * 500,
                maxFiles : 10,
                json : false,
                tailable : true,
            })
        ]
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this: `json : false`

So it looks like this:

```
var winston = require('winston')

var systemLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'system-file',
      json : false,
      // log which stores all the errors
      filename: './test.log',
      json: true,
      timestamp: true
    })
  ]
})
```

You were close, well done for trying!